# How to format email using SMTP

Tags: php, email, formatting, smtp

I'm trying to send formatted email with **php smtp authentication**, but for some reason(s) `\n`, `\r\n` and `PHP_EOL` can not format the message, hence everything appears on a line.

**Below is what I've tried**

```
$order .= "Title : {$title}" . PHP_EOL
."Author : {$author}" . PHP_EOL
."ISBN : {$isbn}" . PHP_EOL
."Publisher : {$publisher}" . PHP_EOL
."Supplier : {$supplier}\n
Quantity : {$qty}\r\n
```

The variable `$order` contains the body of the email.
Here is part of my `sendMail()` function

```
$from = "{$sender_name} <{$sender}>";
$to = $reciever." <$email>";
$subject = $subj;
$body = $msg;
$host = "mail.thekingsbooks.com";           
$username = "noreply@thekingsbooks.com";
$password = "password";

$headers = array(
  'From'    => $from, 
  'To'      => $to, 
  'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory(
  'smtp',
   array(
     'host'   => $host, 
     'auth'   => true,
     username => $username, 
     password => $password
   )
 );

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

**The sent mail looks like this**

```
Ordered items\r\nTitle : A Retreat With Pope John Paul II: Be Not Afraid (Retreat With-- Series)\r\nAuthor : \r\nISBN : 0867164204\r\nPublisher : \r\nSupplier : \r\n\r\n                               Quantity : 6\r\n\r\n
```

Any suggestion on how to format the email body? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing this in Outlook, Outlook may be stripping the whitespace. In Outlook, click on the option that shows the whitespace restored.

Comment: I sent the mail to gmail, I don't use outlook.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that it's being sent as HTML. Trying adding "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" to your headers.